# Deallocate Nodes in Linked List

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

Suppose I have the following implementation of linked list in C:

```
List *create_node(int v) {
    List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    free(node);
    node->value = v;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

List *add_node(List *h, int v) {
    List *node = create_node(v);
    node->next = h;
    return node;
}
```

and I want to deallocate all nodes of a list; and I try to write the function

```
List *remove_list(List *h) {
    while(h != NULL) {
            List *x;
            x = h;
            h =  h->next;
            free(x);
    }
    free(x);
```

}

But it doesn't work. How do you deallocate all the nodes in the linked list?

Comment: OMG!! What is this: `List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    free(node);
    node->value = v;`

Comment: `free` something when you *no longer* need it, not when you *do*. Dunno where that extraneous `free()` came from, but likely just a mistake or a copy-paste issue. Lose the `free()` in `create_node`. The rest looks good save for the outer `free(x)` in your remove_list, which has no chance of even compiling, let alone leading to anything good.

Comment: I get this error while compiling: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o):(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Mat.S completely different issue than the one you posted about.

Comment: Ok, so the code is correct now, just a compile problem?

Comment: @Mat.S Dunno if *your* code is correct or not. Its likely closer if you addressed the previously described issues. And what you just posted isn't a compile problem, its a *link* problem, most likely because the subsystem type is not set to a console application (at least thats how MS' cl works, no idea about gcc on mingw, but I imagine they have something similar).

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question earlier?!

Comment: This is the second time I've seen `free` immediately following `malloc` in code posted to SO ... what gives with that?

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting Seg Fault in your `create_node`  code itself as your dereferencing deallocated memory:

```
...
List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
free(node);
node->value = v;
...
```

You have already `free`d all the nodes that you created, and then dereferenced that location, your `remove_list` will not even be called.

Comment: @MatS: Well, your `remove_list` seems correct, just remove that extra `free` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the last free(x) in remove_list should be free(h), assuming you wanted to remove the list header itself.

But the return of List* suggests maybe you wanted to do return(h) there.

Unclear what you're trying to do here...

Comment: So you are trying to say `free(h)` after the loop which means `free(NULL)`, because of the loop termiantion condition.

Comment: @MadHatter apart from being somewhat pointless, `free(NULL)` is ok, and documented as such. There is no harm in it, but no point either in this case.

Comment: @WhozCraig : But won't `free(NULL)` cause Seg-Fault.

Comment: @MadHatter no. its a no-op. just as `delete p` on a nullptr in C++ is.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your linllist is like

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL
```

when deleting any node you should make sure that you have reference of next node.

when deleting node 1 store reference of node 2 so that in next deletion you can use it to move further in list stop once you encounter NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
List *create_node(int v) {
    List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(node){
        node->value = v;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void remove_list(List *h) {
    while(h != NULL) {
        List *x;
        x = h;
        h =  h->next;
        free(x);
    }
}
```